# How I can get transaction reference in Odoo13

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, odoo-13

In Odoo11, I can get transaction reference by this way

```
transaction = request.website.sale_get_order().payment_tx_id
transaction.reference
```

But in Odoo13, `payment_tx_id` field has removed from sales order,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Field *Many2one (payment_tx_id) to Many2many (transaction_ids)* type changed from Odoo12.

Try with following code:

```
order = request.website.sale_get_order()

#if you need to get last transaction
transaction = order.get_portal_last_transaction()
reference = transaction.reference



#if you need all reference to listed
reference =  str(', '.join(order.transaction_ids.mapped('reference')))
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I don't no why I get **False** when I print  **transaction.reference**

Comment: Reference will be null that's why, which code you applied?.

Comment: from the first method, and I get **transaction reference** from the second method
***references = order.transaction_ids.mapped('reference')
print(references[0])***